# Selenium Python I am getting an empty string from a text element but there is a value on the GUI

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some text displayed on the GUI.  I have identified the element using it's XPATH from Xpath Checker from Firebug.  The element highlights correctly.
In my code i use the text attribute to to print out it's value.
I would like to print the value to the console.
When i walk through the code using PyCharm debugger I can see the variable text attribute is empty.
Why has the variable not got the text value?

My code snippet is:

```
def is_engine_number_displayed(self):
    engine_no_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "Engine: 5.1.1")]')
    print "engine_no_element.text***"
    print engine_no_element.text
    #return engine_no_element.text in "Engine: 5.1.1"
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="GJPPK2LBKQ">
<a class="gwt-Anchor GJPPK2LBMQ" title="Click for about">Client: 5.1.1.6044</a>
<a class="gwt-Anchor GJPPK2LBMQ" title="Click for about">Engine: 5.1.1.5218</a>
```

My XPATH to locate the text Engine: 5.1.1

```
//a[contains(., "Engine: 5.1.1")]
```

Using the XPATH the text Engine: 5.1.1 is highlighted on the GUI

get_element is in my Base class.  It's implementation is:

```
# returns the element if found
def get_element(self, how, what):
    # params how: By locator type
    # params what: locator value
    try:
        element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print what
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        screenshot_name = how + what + get_datetime_now() # create screenshot name of the name of the element + locator + todays date time.  This way the screenshot name will be unique and be able to save
        self.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)
        raise
    return element
```

Why is my element text value empty?

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Could you please show what is `get_element`?

Comment: Did you tried to avoid you own function `get_element()`: just using `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Engine: 5.1.1")]').text`?

Comment: I have edited my question and included my get_element code.

Comment: @RiazLadhani interesting case. What if you setup and endless loop and print out the `.text` value - would you always see empty, or it goes to `Engine: 5.1.1.5218` after several loop cycles? Thanks.

Comment: I have tried self.driver_find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'Engine: 5.1.1')]") I am getting unresolved attribute reference for find_element_by_xpath.  I need to import something.  I tried import from selenium import webdriver.  It's not that one.  Do you know which one i need to import?

Comment: I have asked the dev to put an ID on this element.  The Text attribute works for other elements.  I will try in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem when I tried to verify the population of text fields after a selection is made from a dropdown.  As you mentioned, the texts are indeed there, but selenium thinks they are empty.  If memory serves, it was because the form had not been submitted yet, and I believe the value attribute (not the text attribute) is where the getText() function actually pulls its data.  The value attribute does not get set until later.  Take a look at the elements' value attribute after you submit the page, and I believe those values will be set, and the getText() will return the correct text values.  I was not able to find a work-around, since upon the user clicking the submit button, it was proceeding to the next web page.